# Play Music player instead of Alarm

Tags: android, cron-task

Is it possible to start music player at specific time i.e. instead playing a single alarm tone, is it possible to start Music player when alarm runs..?

Can user set cron job in android or it must be set by developer...?

Comment: Android doesn't have cron, but it has `AlarmManager` with same (or broader) capabilities, accessible through programming interface for applications.

Comment: So using `AlarmManager` can I start music app? @VallyN

Comment: You need to register `BroadcastReceiver` which will be invoked by `AlarmManager` to start music player app, because AM works only with broadcasts and can't run activity directly.